# Update column values to integers

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a column in my table that I need to change the data type from `VARCHAR` to `DOUBLE`. Now I cannot convert it to `DOUBLE` data type easily because the values on that column have numbers and strings.

```
> 0 41  14:16:57
  ALTER TABLE `ControlAutomation`.`constantcomponentstabular`
     DROP COLUMN `String`,
     CHANGE COLUMN `ConstantValue` `ConstantValue` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL

> Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'ConstantValue' at row 217966 1.891 sec
```

I know what is causing this issue, its because there are strings on the column that I want to change to `DOUBLE`.

Here is the solution that I have in mind using Python

1. Query the table.
2. Check whether the value can be converted to `float`.
3. If not, `UPDATE` value of that column to `0`.

This process takes a long time, My question is how to best change those values to any number so I will be able to ALTER the table.

I am using `MySQL 5.6.32` and `InnoDB` as storage engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me suggest to add a new column and then update this new column before to drop the old one.

1. **Backup, backup, backup**

> ```
> create table mytable (ConstantValue varchar(100));
>
> insert into mytable values
> ('1252.36'),('abc'),('55969'),('def'),('66955663'),('A8879'),('-41.25'),('+636');
> ```

2. Add a new column with a default value of 0.

> ```
> alter table mytable
>     add column NewConstantValue double default(0);
> ```

3. Set alphanumeric values to 0. I've borrowed this regex expression from [MySql forums](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,599995,599995)

> ```
> update mytable
> set    ConstantValue = '0'
> where  ConstantValue not regexp '^(-|\\+)?([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$';
> ```

4. Update new column with current values.

> ```
> update mytable
> set    NewConstantValue = cast(ConstantValue as double);
> ```

5. **Check new values before to drop old column.**

> ```
> select * from mytable;
> ```
>
> ```
> ConstantValue | NewConstantValue
> :------------ | ---------------:
> 1252.36       |          1252.36
> 0             |                0
> 55969         |            55969
> 0             |                0
> 66955663      |         66955663
> 0             |                0
> -41.25        |           -41.25
> +636          |              636
> ```

6. Drop `ConstantValue` column.

> ```
> alter table mytable
>     drop column ConstantValue;
> ```

7. Rename new column as ConstantValue.

> ```
> alter table mytable
>     change column NewConstantValue ConstantValue double default(0);
> ```

8. Check final result.

> ```
> select * from mytable;
> ```
>
> ```
> | ConstantValue |
> | ------------: |
> |       1252.36 |
> |             0 |
> |         55969 |
> |             0 |
> |      66955663 |
> |             0 |
> |        -41.25 |
> |           636 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=1761fe63d4aa6787eae375e29f4fdbeb)*

Comment: Why do you format all your code  additionally as citation?

Comment: @miracle173 follow dbfiddle.uk link and click markdown button.

Comment: thank you very much for this solution and I avoided using Python! this works, the only different thing is when casting to double, MySQL has a different format. `CAST(Value as Decimal(4,2))` This is what I used.

Comment: I'm glad to help

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to the solution by @McNets, you can use a `CONTINUE HANDLER` to handle casting errors:

```
delimiter //
create or replace function str2double(s varchar(10))
returns double
deterministic
begin
    declare continue handler for sqlstate '22007' return 0;
    return cast(s as double);
end //
delimiter ;

update mytable set ConstantValue = str2double(ConstantValue);

drop function str2double;
```

Now all values in column should be valid doubles, and you can alter the table.